# Trans, hash, and character classes in Perl 6

Tags: raku

When I use a `regex` as the first argument of `trans`, it's OK:

```perl6
> say 'abc'.trans(/\w <?before b>/ => 1)
1bc
```

Using a `hash` as an argument of `trans` is also OK:

```perl6
> my %h
> %h{'a'} = '1'
> say 'abc'.trans(%h)
1bc
```

But when I try to use regexes in a hash, it doesn't work:

```perl6
> my %h
> %h{'/\w/'} = '1'
> say 'abc'.trans(%h)
abc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```perl6
'/\w/'
```

is not a regex, it is a string.

---

```perl6
my %h{Any};         # make sure it accepts non-Str keys
%h{/\w/} = 1;
say 'abc'.trans(%h)
```

```
111
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @evb Also note that to make a hash that specifically and only accepts `Regex` as the key type, you can declare: `my %h{Regex}`.